# Migration from SQL 2012 Server to Oracle 11g

Tags: sql-server, oracle11g, sql-server-2012, migration, oracle-sqldeveloper

How can i migrate from SQL Server 2012 to Oracle 11g?

I have used Oracle SQL developer. Its working for SQL Server 2008 but not for SQL Server 2012.

Is there any other tool which might be helpful?